# Firebase .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { fires after my method has ended

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a method that reads some data from the firebase database.
Let's call it `getMyData()` 
I am attaching a `firebaseQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...`.

My code structure is something like this. 
`SomeDataType myData = getMyData(); if(myData==someCondition){//some logic} else{//some logic}`

The problem is that the event listener doesn't get fired until my code has passed.

So something like this happens `SomeDataType = null` and it goes to my where clause. 
 `firebase` uses events so it's not linear code execution but I am a little confused... Can you help me?

Comment: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is asynchronous.  That's the way it works.  It's not going to block your app to wait for the results of the query, which could take any amount of time.  https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93

Comment: @DougStevenson any idea how to approach my problem?

Comment: You'll have to learn asynchronous programming techniques and apply that to the use of Firebase APIs.  I'll suggest doing the Firebase Android codelab to get some experience.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok I understand that it is async... anyway how would you approach this problem... You need some data that you have to use further for the business logic. You have to fetch it ofc.

Comment: Check my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).

Comment: @AlexMamo your post was pretty good, anyway what if my callback must accept an argument?

Comment: There will be no problem. Add a another argument, will work fine.

Comment: @AlexMamo in other words from where do I pass the "String value"?

Comment: @AlexMamo oh sorry my mistake... anyway thanks. U deserve an upvote